# using insert uo update cassandra using the same primary key,but failed

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Using `insert` update Cassandra using the same primary key, but failed.  I tried many times to update one row in Cassandra using the same PK with insert CQL, but didn't change the value in Cassandra.

Cassandra version : 3.11.8

Comment: Could you share a CQL portion that you are using to solve your problem ?

Comment: INSERT INTO data_kv_cf (type,partition,key,id,long_v) VALUES ('DEVICE',1609430400000,'countIn',42b56820-5641-11eb-a855-d5209b2a38e8,666);where type,partition,key,id is the primary key